# Doctrine query builder order by field

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

Can anyone tell me the similar query in Doctrine to get in the order we pass inside IN() function.

```
SELECT * FROM user 
WHERE id IN (5,2,3,1,4) 
ORDER BY FIELD(id,5,2,3,1,4)
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seems like you can use the `FIELD` function with Doctrine. But you can still use the [Doctrine 2 extension project](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) which add support for additional query functions.